# How do you pass a prop to an onChange function in Redux-Form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-form

So say I have the following component (this is pseudo code, but should illustrate my problem in a much shorter reading format hopefully)...

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  onChange = () => {
    store.dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_VENUE', location: locationValue })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.id) // "2"
    return (
      <Field id="salesArea" name="orderHeader.salesArea" type="select" onChange={this.onChange}
             component={SelectComponent} />
    )
  }
}

export default Example;
```

If I have a prop from the Container component ExampleContainer that provides a value at this.prop.id. How can I pass this as locationValue so basically the equivalent of

`location: this.props.id`

without creating an anti-pattern.

this.props.id uses formValueSelector in the HOC to return the current value of salesArea.

My code works great if I set location: '2' for instance, but is there a way to pass a prop into this dispatch?

Comment: you should have the dispatch in the actions file, and you can define this action in your mapDisptachToProps. In onChange event call the action you have passed, which will internally dispatch the payload to all reducers

Comment: what is the problem with `store.dispatch({type: 'FETCH_VENUE', location: this.props.id})`

Comment: It returns undefined. (or a warning about an anti pattern). I think @ShreyKejriwal put me on the right track, but I was trying to test it all in a single component prior to moving it into mapDispatchToProps (mapStateToProps) is already in the HOC which is how i'm getting this.props.id in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that stumbles upon this. I solved it as follows.

I added the following function in the simple Form component.

```
onVenueChange = (event, venueId) => {
    console.log(venueId);
    this.props.onVenueChange(venueId)
}
```

I then call it like this in the < Field />

```
call onChange={this.onVenueChange}
```

In an HOC as part of mapDispatch I have the following. Which dispatches the action.

```
onVenueChange: venueId => dispatch({type: 'FETCH_EDITABLEORDERS', venueId: venueId })
```